# Does ALL content in the Files folder get packaged?

Tags: basic4android

This problem has baffled me for a while. 
One day I ran my program.  It went through the normal steps in the console.  Finally it got to installing to my device.  It would time out and then give me an error saying to restart adb.

I restarted adb with no luck.  Every now and then it would work BUT it would take 500 sec.!!!!
My app only had about 2 mb of files.

Finally today out of pure accident I was browsing the folder of my app.  I noticed that the APK created was 75 mb!!!

I looked in my Files folder and I noticed I had created a folder inside to store some larger files that I didn't need in my APK.  These files in this folder were 73 mb.  It seems B4A is including these files.

I thought the only files included would be files added with the file manager.  Even when I selected "Clean Files (unused)", it didn't list these files stored in the extra folder.

If b4a is including ALL files and folders in the Files folder, then  "Clean Files (unused)" should include these as well.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

The packaging tool which is part of Android SDK packages all of the files.
Clean all files should delete unused files. Maybe the files are used by one of the layout files?

Comment: I created a folder inside the Files folder.  It's name was "PSD", inside this folder I imported 10 images from my camera.  The images had names like "IMG_123234.jpg".  They are not referenced anywhere in my code.  For some reason b4a packaged them into my apk.  If I remove this folder from the Files folder, no errors occur, only the APK becomes 70 mb smaller.  This is why I was wondering if b4a just packages everything in the Files folder.

Comment: The packaging tool packages all files and folders under the Files folder.

Comment: Thanks.  That's all I wanted to confirm.  Hopefully this tread will help someone else as well.